# MVC View sorting

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have received complex data from the controller in the view.
Manipulating the data for the D3 was surprisingly easier than I expected.
The problem I am having now is that I want to have the ability to sort the data in different ways.
I have resolved this in a way that I think is tremendously inefficient.

I created 3 radio buttons, assigned a function to the onclick event, that function performs a submit (I have a hidden input for the sorting option), the controller performs a new set of queries to the DB and sorts the data in the required way before presenting it.

I have been reading about "how to" do this with MVC and it seems like I have done something very similar to what it is expected however, I cannot believe there is no way to resort/postback the data once it is in the View.

Is it that I do not understand the model, is it that I have not looked hard enough, is it that I do not understand the answers, or is it a combination of all these plus me being a worst coder than what I thought I was?

PS: I can post code specifics (eye sores) but this seems to be more of a conceptual question rather than a specific one.

*EDIT: Added the code snippets below. Please let me know if it makes sense.*

**Code snippets:**

*Controller:*

```
   // GET: /Home/Search
    public ActionResult Search(string txtNetwork, string previousnet, string RB)
    {                 
        if ((txtNetwork == "" || txtNetwork == "undefined" || txtNetwork == null) && (previousnet == "" || previousnet == "undefined" || previousnet == null))
        {
            Utilization u = new Utilization();
            BLL.BLL bll = new BLL.BLL();


            Totals tots = new Totals();

            tots.networks = 0;
            tots.ips = 0;

            ViewBag.tots = bll.GetTotalsNetsAndIps();

            u = bll.GetNetworks(0);

            SortDisplay(u.nets, RB);

            ViewBag.u = u;

            return View();
        }
```

*View:*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("txtNetwork")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="previousnet" value="" />

    <label>Sort By: @Html.RadioButton("RB", "Mask", ViewData["IsSelected"] == "Mask", new { onclick = "sortdata(txtNetwork);" })Mask</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("RB", "Net", ViewData["IsSelected"] == "Net", new { onclick = "sortdata(txtNetwork);" })Net</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("RB", "Utilization", ViewData["IsSelected"] == "Utilization", new { onclick = "previousnet.value = txtNetwork.value;sortdata(txtNetwork);" })Utilization</label>


}
```

....

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var gauges = [];
    var netnames = [];
    var netlabels = [];
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.u));
    var totalnodes = [];
    var utilized = [];
    var globali = 0;
    var totalnets = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.tots.networks);
    var totalips = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.tots.ips);

    var marginleft = 10,
        marginright = 10,
        margintop = 50,
        marginbottom = 50;

    var scrollbarwidth = 30;
    var generalwidth = screen.availWidth;
    var generalheight = screen.availHeight;
    var panelwidth = generalwidth / 2 - 2;
    var panelheight = generalheight / 2 - margintop - marginbottom;




    </script>
```

*Worker functions:*

```
function sendinfo(name)
{
    var form = document.forms[0];
    document.getElementById("txtNetwork").value = name;

    form.submit();
}

function sortdata(previousnetwork)
{
    var form = document.forms[0];
    form.submit();
}

function  generatearrays()
{
    for (var key in data.nets) {

        if (data.nets.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            netlabels.push(data.nets[key].network);
            netnames.push("n" + key);

            var nodetotal = Math.pow(2, (32 - data.nets[key].mask)) - 2;
            if (nodetotal > 0) {
                totalnodes.push(nodetotal);
            }
            else {

                totalnodes.push(1);
            }
            utilized.push(data.nets[key].utilization);

        }
    }
}

function processdata()
{
    generatearrays();
    generatehtmlforbars();
    generatestatstopright();
    generatestatsbottomright();
}
```

Models...:

```
namespace VLANS_mvc.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Utilization
    {
        public List<VisualNetwork> nets { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace VLANS_mvc.Models
{
    public class VisualNetwork
    {

        public string network { get; set; }
        public int mask { get; set; }
        public int usedipcount { get; set; }
        public int utilization { get; set; }


    }
}

namespace VLANS_mvc.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Totals
    {
        public int networks { get; set; }
        public int ips { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is, post the code you have - all the relevant bits from the model, view and controller.

Comment: Haven't heard any news yet....anyone willing to give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: (sorry for the delay, I was OOF)
Added the models although they do not seem to be very relevant to the question :(
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you will need to create another method in your controller which will accept the POSTing of the data and will take your model of the data as an argument, you could have this scheduled to fire once your sorting has been completed

Comment: Ok, I can explore that....thanks....
From my understanding of how this work, there's no way I can sort on the client side and get it to post the results again, correct?

Comment: No there is I said in my last comment that you could have a method to post the data back to the controller that triggers after the data has sorted